# Perform the validation loss from .caffemodel?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

AFAIK, we have two ways to obtain the validation loss.
(1) online during training process by setting the solver as follows:
train_net: `'train.prototxt'`

```
test_net: "test.prototxt"
test_iter: 200
test_interval: 100
```

(2) offline based on the weight in the .caffemodel file. In this question, I regard to the second way due to limited GPU. First, I saved the weight of network to .caffemodel after each 100 iterations by `snapshot: 100`. Based on these .caffemodel, I want to calculate the validation loss

```
../build/tools/caffe test -model ./test.prototxt -weights $snapshot -iterations 10 -gpu 0
```

where `snapshot` is file name of .caffemodel. For example `snap_network_100.caffemodel`

And the data layer of my test prototxt is

```
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "HDF5Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
  hdf5_data_param {
    source: "./list.txt"
    batch_size: 8
    shuffle: true
  }
}
```

The first and the second ways give different validation loss. I found that the first way the validation loss independent of batch size. It means the validation loss is same with different batch size. While, the second way, the validation loss changed with different batch size but the loss is very close together with different iterations.

My question is that which way is correct to compute validation loss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You compute the validation loss for **different** number of iterations:

```
test_iter: 200
```

In your `'solver.prototxt'`, vs. `-iterations 10` when running from command line. This means you are averaging the loss over different number of validation samples.
Since you are using far less samples when validating from command line, you are much more sensitive to batch_size.
Make sure you are using **exactly** the same settings and verify that the validation loss is indeed the same.

Comment: Sorry. I typo it. It must be 100. Regard to the iterations parameter. Which number should I use?

Comment: @user8264 `test_iter`*`batch_size` should equal the number of validatoin samples you have in your validation set (i.e., validating over ALL set).

Comment: Thanks. This is a good knowledge. One more thing, do you think two ways in my question will be similar results when I have a correct setting. In additions, what is `-iterations` should I chose?

Comment: when running `caffe test` from command line, caffe runs the validation for `-iterations XX` number of iterations. `XX` should be the same as `test_iter: XX` in `'solver.prototxt'` file.

Comment: Thanks you. I got it.